# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate erro

Tags: android

Está a acontecer este erro na minha aplicação:

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate

o meu código de imagem:

```
URL url1 = null;
    try {
        url1 = new URL("http://www.cm-mgrande.pt" + cabecalho);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    try {
        InputStream input = url1.openConnection().getInputStream();
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        input.close();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(url1.openStream()));
        in.close();
        imgcabecalho.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        imgcabecalho.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();


    }
```

o meu Android Manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


    <activity
        android:name=".Index"
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >



    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Para que é aquele `BufferedReader`?

Comment: Uma boa pergunta mas na altura precisei para correr o código

Comment: No código que postou ele não está a fazer nada. O erro pode ser por não haver memoria suficiente para alocar o `BufferedReader`. Elimine-o e tente de novo. Se não for suficiente veja esta resposta no SOen. Nada tem a haver com o erro mas será necessário incluir no *Manifest.xml* a permissão de acesso à *internet*

Comment: erro ao copiar eu estou a usar  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

Comment: removi os bufferedreader e nada funcionou ainda

Comment: O erro é o mesmo ou é outro? Por esquecimento não coloquei o link para a [resposta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16528487/2556111) que referi no outro comentário.

Comment: é o mesmo agora tentei assim 

Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input,options);  mas da erro no options

Comment: BitmapFactory.Options options=new BitmapFactory.Options(); 
options.inSampleSize=2; 
InputStream input = url1.openConnection().getInputStream(); 
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input,options); 
input.close();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provavelmente o Bitmap é grande demais para a memória alocada pelo seu app. A documentação recomenda diversos cuidados ao lidar com criação de Bitmaps, especialmente em função da memória. [Aqui tem bastante informação útil](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html).

Recomendo que você crie um bitmap de acordo com o tamanho que será exibido. Para isso você precisa primeiro marcar o **bitmap** como **inJustDecodeBounds**, assim você só pegara as informações dele para fazer uma redução de escala e não o carregará na memória.

```
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath , options );

    // faça o cálculo da sua escala
    int imageWidth = options.outWidth;
    scale   = Math.round( imageHeight / width );
    options.inSampleSize    = scale;

    //Remove marcação e inicia o trabalho no bitmap
    options.inJustDecodeBounds  = false;

    // Cria o bitmap com o tamanho reduzido
    Bitmap scaledBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath , options);
```

Esta operação é custosa e não recomendo que você a faça na UI. Cria um AsyncTask ou algo assim.
Uma dica é que existem diversas librarys muito boas que fazem este serviço. A [Universal Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) funciona muito bem.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Totalmente certo, ajudou muito! Obrigado!